# .NET Core ThreadPool Queue Length

Tags: multithreading, .net-core, threadpool, dotnet-counters

There is a vague topic about threads in .NET for me.

This is a result of `dotnet-counters`:

```
[System.Runtime]
% Time in GC since last GC (%)                               8
Allocation Rate (B / 1 sec)                                  64,202,240
CPU Usage (%)                                                81
Exception Count (Count / 1 sec)                              33
GC Committed Bytes (MB)                                      332
GC Fragmentation (%)                                         21.929
GC Heap Size (MB)                                            246
Gen 0 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                               3
Gen 0 Size (B)                                               24
Gen 1 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                               1
Gen 1 Size (B)                                               14,135,448
Gen 2 GC Count (Count / 1 sec)                               0
Gen 2 Size (B)                                               1.6342e+08
IL Bytes Jitted (B)                                          9,143,138
LOH Size (B)                                                 1.6319e+08
Monitor Lock Contention Count (Count / 1 sec)                79
Number of Active Timers                                      75
Number of Assemblies Loaded                                  410
Number of Methods Jitted                                     103,574
POH (Pinned Object Heap) Size (B)                            1,521,664
ThreadPool Completed Work Item Count (Count / 1 sec)         1,648
ThreadPool Queue Length                                      101
ThreadPool Thread Count                                      13
Time spent in JIT (ms / 1 sec)                               1,451.124
Working Set (MB)                                             649
```

It is clear that 13 active threads are used from the threadpool and 101 requests are queued.

While the cpu consumption has not yet reached 100% and the number of active threads is very low (as far as I know, the number of threads based on the system can be very large, for example 200,000).

In this situation, why are the requests in the queue when a new thread should have been created for them

Comment: I suppose, you are talking about ASP.NET MVC requests.
In order to answer that, we need more information. Most importantly, is whether your actions are sync or async. Do you have some I/O calls, which are synchronous?